# iPhone automatic updates is a puzzle

Tags: iphone, auto-update

I'm trying to understand the **automatic download** on iPhone.

On Apple's documentation it specifically states:

[image: If you turn on Updates, any new versions of apps that you currently have on your device automatically download when they're available.]

My setting is set to download apps automatically:

[image]

However, I have tons of apps waiting to be updated:

[image]

Comment: It'll only update when connected to power and Wi-Fi

Comment: @Harcker - well it's connected to WiFi and power for hours now and nothing gets updated...

Answer (score 1):

In the "More about [Automatic Downloads](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202180)" section:

> If your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch has an Internet connection and you
>   turn on Push Notifications, your content automatically downloads to
>   your device. On an associated device that doesn't support Push
>   Notifications, your content automatically appears in your iTunes
>   download queue. You can manually download the content in iTunes.

I had turned off push notifications for the App Store and automatic updates stopped working. After I turned it on again it started working as usual.

Comment: sorry, but I have push turned on for App Store and still need to manually update apps.